# Node.js - Creating Relationships with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have 2 Schemas, `Custphone` and `Subdomain`. `Custphone` `belongs_to` a `Subdomain` and `Subdomain` `has_many` `Custphones`.

The problem is in creating the relationship using Mongoose. My goal is to do: custphone.subdomain and get the Subdomain that the Custphone belongs to.

I have this in my schemas:

```
SubdomainSchema = new Schema
    name : String

CustphoneSchema = new Schema
    phone : String
    subdomain  : [SubdomainSchema]
```

When I print the Custphone result I get this:

```
{ _id: 4e9bc59b01c642bf4a00002d,
  subdomain: [] }
```

When the `Custphone` result has `{"$oid": "4e9b532b01c642bf4a000003"}` in MongoDB.

**I want to do `custphone.subdomain` and get the subdomain object of the custphone.**

Comment: @Mike Robinson - I want to do custphone.subdomain and get the subdomain object of the custphone.

Answer (score 125):

It sounds like you're looking to try the new [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) functionality in Mongoose.

Using your example above:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

SubdomainSchema = new Schema
    name : String

CustphoneSchema = new Schema
    phone : String
    subdomain  : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'SubdomainSchema' }
```

The `subdomain` field will be is updated with an '_id' such as:

```
var newSubdomain = new SubdomainSchema({name: 'Example Domain'})
newSubdomain.save()

var newCustphone = new CustphoneSchema({phone: '123-456-7890', subdomain: newSubdomain._id})
newCustphone.save()
```

To actually get data from the `subdomain` field you're going to have to use the slightly more complex query syntax:

```
CustphoneSchema.findOne({}).populate('subdomain').exec(function(err, custPhone) { 
// Your callback code where you can access subdomain directly through custPhone.subdomain.name 
})
```

Comment: Is this still valid for the newest version of mongoose?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me with some config with `mongoose#3.8.3`.

Comment: Maybe it has changed but, run doesn't seem to exist. I had to use .exec!

Comment: I used this with Mongoose 4.4.12 and it still works. This works for me and the code examples in the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) do not, although I'm new to Mongoose.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and had to use mongoose's Model.findByIdAndUpdate()

docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

this post helped me also: http://blog.ocliw.com/2012/11/25/mongoose-add-to-an-existing-array/comment-page-1/#comment-17812