# Mongoose Relationship Populate Doesn't Return results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    var SecuritySchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
        _bids: [{
            type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'BuyOrder'
        }],
        _asks: [{
            type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'SellOrder'
        }]
    });

    var OrdersSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
        _security: {
            type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Security'
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    });


    // declare seat covers here too
    var models = {
        Security: Mongoose.model('Security', SecuritySchema),
        BuyOrder: Mongoose.model('BuyOrder', OrdersSchema),
        SellOrder: Mongoose.model('SellOrder', OrdersSchema)
    };
    return models;
```

And than when I save a new `BuyOrder` for example:

```
// I put the 'id' of the security: order.__security = security._id on the client-side
var order = new models.BuyOrder(req.body.order);
    order.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
```

And attempt to re-retrieve the associated security:

```
models.Security.findById(req.params.id).populate({
        path: '_bids'
    }).exec(function(err, security) {
        // the '_bids' array is empty.
    });
```

I think this is some sort of naming issue, but I'm not sure, I've seen examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810892/node-js-creating-relationships-with-mongoose) and on the moongoose website that use `Number` as the `Id` type: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` field should use the singular model name

Also, just do:

```
models.Security.findById(req.params.id).populate('_bids').exec(...
```

My main suspicion given your snippet at the moment is your `req.body.order` has `_security` as a string instead of an array containing a string.

Also, you don't need an `id` property. Mongodb itself will automatically do the `_id` as a real BSON ObjectId, and mongoose will add `id` as a string representation of the same value, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Awesome- so like `_security: {
            type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Security'
        },` Do I define a new singular model type? I'll give it a try! Nice hair btw! Will report back shortly.

Comment: Updated my answer with another thing to change, but can you please post the exact contents of `req.body.order`?

Answer (score -1):

While I don't understand your schema (and the circular nature of it?), this code works:

```
var order = new models.BuyOrder({ price: 100, quantity: 5});
order.save(function(err, orderDoc) {
    var security = new models.Security();
    security._bids.push(orderDoc);
    security.save(function(err, doc) {
       models.Security.findById({ _id: doc._id })
           .populate("_bids").exec(function(err, security) {
              console.log(security);

           });
    });
});
```

It:

1. creates a `BuyOrder`
2. `save`s it
3. creates a `Security`
4. adds to the array of `_bids` the new `orderDoc`'s `_id`
5. saves it
6. searches for the match and populates

Note that there's not an automatic method for adding the document to the array of _bids, so I've done that manually.

Results:

```
{ _id: 5224e73af7c90a2017000002,
  __v: 0,
  _asks: [],
  _bids: [ { price: 100, 
           quantity: 5, 
           _id: 5224e72ef7c90a2017000001, __v: 0 } ] }
```

Comment: Well in reference to being 'circular' don't I need some way to associate a new `order` to the `security`? I get what your doing when you "push" the new 'order' into the '_bids' but what I don't want to create a new security for each `_bid` or `_ask` would I just call an `update` after I push a new `order` into the array?

Comment: You'd only need to associate the new order to the security if you want to be able to do a bidirectional lookup. It's up to you. You'd just call `update` and `$push` a new item into the array anytime there's a new order.

Comment: gotcha - that makes sense ... I just thought I could create the `order` by itself, this does kind of bode with the documentation on the mongoose page and using a `push` procedure.