# How insert one data into one collection(userModel) as well as aslo same data insert into another collection(Attendance) in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

How insert one data into one collection(userModel) as well as aslo same data insert into another collection(Attendance) in mongodb.How I can do??

one collection userModel

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'srId': { type: Number },
    'empId': { type: String },
    'empName': { type: String },
    'designation': { type: String },
    'blStartDate': { type: Date },
    'startDateAtCompany': { type: Date },
    'endDate': { type: Date },
    'mobile': { type: String },
    'panCard': { type: String },
    'email': { type: String },
    'dob': { type: Date },
    'empContractSigned': { type: String },
    'offerLetter': { type: String },
    'empFormCsr': { type: String },
    'originalSubmitted': { type: String },
    'password': { type: String },
    'otp': { type: String },
});
let userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', userSchema, 'userModel');
exports.userModel = userModel;
```

other collection is Attendance

```
let AttendanceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'mobile': { type: Schema.Types.mobile, ref: 'userModel' },
    'time': [{
        'inTime': { type: String },
        'outTime': { type: String },
        'totalTime': { type: String },
        'syncTime': { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    }]
})

let Attendance = mongoose.model('Attendance', AttendanceSchema, 'Attendance');
exports.Attendance = Attendance;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - Creating Relationships with Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810892/node-js-creating-relationships-with-mongoose)

Comment: this method is deprecated

Comment: what do you want to do? Create an `user` model and then insert its id into `attendance` model?

Comment: @ravi shankar ...how achieve one to many relationship? e.g. one user have multiple days of attendance.